# NSDate messes up my date!  Wrong timezone?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

```
NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@",currTime,sunrise,sunset);
NSString *curtime = [[currTime substringToIndex:(currTime.length-4)] stringByAppendingString:@"-0000"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]autorelease];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm aZ"];
[formatter1 setLocale:locale];

NSDate *time = [formatter1 dateFromString:curtime];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEE dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *zone = [formatter1 stringFromDate:time];
NSString *r = [sunrise stringByAppendingString:zone];
NSString *s = [sunset stringByAppendingString:zone];

[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm aEEE dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *rise = [formatter1 dateFromString:r];
NSDate *set = [formatter1 dateFromString:s];

unsigned int flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:rise];
NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:set];
NSDateComponents *components3 = [calendar components:flags fromDate:time];

NSInteger riseHour = [components1 hour];
NSInteger setHour = [components2 hour];
NSInteger timeHour = [components3 hour];

NSLog(@"\nSunrise: %@ \nSunset: %@ \nCurrent: %@",rise,set,time);
NSLog(@"Rise: %i  Set: %i  Time: %i",riseHour,setHour,timeHour);
```

I'd expect this to work.  However, look at the output below:

Sun, 12 Jun 2011 1:54 am CDT - 6:33 am - 8:34 pm

Sunrise: 2011-06-11 21:33:00 +0000

Sunset: 2011-06-12 11:34:00 +0000

Current: 2011-06-12 01:54:00 +0000

Rise: 6  < correct

Set: 20  < correct

Time: 10 < wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the timezone to GMT-0 on both the formatter *and the calendar*.  You might be pleasantly surprised.

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]
```